# How to delete duplicate rows in a pandas dataframe such that only the last entry will be deleted

Tags: python, pandas

How to delete duplicate rows such that only the last duplicate entry will be deleted. The pandas drop_duplicates func will only keep either the first entry or last entry but I need all the entries except the last one.

Eg:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({"col1": list('acbcaa')})
```

Desired output

```
X = pd.DataFrame({"col1": list('acba')})
```

Comment: `X[X.duplicated(keep='last') | ~X.duplicated(keep=False)]`?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny a) you're clearly a wizard, that's brilliant, b) that seems like it would be better as an answer than a comment, perhaps?